# Certain $http request not working on iOS Emulators or Devices (but fine on everything else)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

hope you are well.

I am currently trying to call an API we have designed on a C# WebAPI which will call successfully on devices. However, on occasion, it will not call on the iOS Platform. This is how I have the calling of the API setup:

```
$scope.RunNews = function() {
    console.log("Testing 123. I don't know!")
    var app_url_news = APP_URL.getUrl() + '/api/news/getallnewsinfo';

    $http.get(app_url_news).success(function(data) {
      console.log("Successful Transfer. Data Below")
      console.log(data);

      angular.forEach(data.data, function(obj) {
        console.log(obj);
        if (obj.videoUrl) {
          if (Validators.isValidYoutubeUrl(obj.videoUrl)) {
            var youtubeVideoId = obj.videoUrl.split('v=')[1].split('&')[0];
            obj.videoUrl = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + youtubeVideoId + '?html5=1&amp;rel=0&amp;hl=en_US&amp;version=3';
          }
          obj.isVideo = true;
        } else {
          obj.imagePath = APP_URL.getUrl() + '/NewsImages/files/' + obj.imagePath;
          obj.isVideo = MediaType.isVideo(obj.imagePath);
        }
      });

      $scope.newsList = data.data;

      $ionicLoading.hide();
  });
}
}
```

Currently, this function calls on the ionic serve web browsing emulator and android devices... HOWEVER, on iOS, the $http is never called. I have noticed that this is apparent for multiple $http calls but for others, they work fine.

I'm here to ask if anyone has experienced this issue and has a fix for it? I believe it may have something to do with permissions but I cannot seem to find anything in my project.

Comment: When you run the app on an iOS device or simulator, open up Safari and go to the Develop menu - and view the console. Check the network tab and see whats happening with the API call. Report back with your findings.

Comment: I have discovered that the function doesn't run at all but I am as to confused why as it runs fine on Android and the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. GET requests couldn't be made on iOS devices but were working in the browser. I fixed the issue by installing [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist). To use it, you must have Cordova version 4.0 or greater.

If the problem persists, you should debug the app for any logs in console and check the request's response and request headers. These will help you pin down what the problem is.

Comment: Yes, I already have that plugin install and its not working. We have debunked that it may be the use of http instead of https but we are still uncertain as we cannot test accurately as of today (19/03/2018)

Comment: That could be possible but you can sent me the log and the response headers if you want any help.